# Space shooter, shooting bug

Tags: c#, xna

I have a space shooter with rotational movement and shooting but when I shoot the bullets come  out slightly to the left or right when moving how do I fix this Thanks :)

```
Bullets newBullet = new Bullets(Content.Load<Texture2D>("PlayerBullet"));
newBullet.velocity = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(rotation),
                                 (float)Math.Sin(rotation)) * 5f + playerVelocity;
newBullet.position = playerPosition + newBullet.velocity * 5;
```

here is some code I think that's causing the problem

Comment: call it 'a Hard Mode feature'

Comment: Haha but no easy mode :P

Comment: Why does the `playerVelocity` affect the bullet? Will the bullet go faster when the player is moving?

Comment: Yes the bullet will go faster :)

Comment: Why does the last line contain `* 5`? It looks like you are multiplying the `newBullet.velocity` when you should just be adding.

Comment: It gets an error if i do that :(

Comment: You probably need to subtract `playerVelocity` from `newBullet.position`. The initial position does probably not depend on the player's velocity. If that's not the case, please post some screen shots. Otherwise it is impossible to tell what's wrong.

Comment: load texture only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your position and velocity calculations are incorrect.

The initial position should simply be the player's position (plus possibly an offset if carrying a gun for example)

```
newBullet.position = playerPosition;
```

I'm not sure why you are adding the players velocity to the bullet. Why should it matter how fast the player is moving? I also assume the `* 5f` if just a speed coefficient.

```
newBullet.velocity = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(rotation), (float)Math.Sin(rotation)) * 5f;
```

Try that out and see if that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect the initial position of the bullet to be

```
newBullet.position = playerPosition + playerVelocity * 5;
```

instead of

```
newBullet.position = playerPosition + newBullet.velocity * 5;
```

Comment: @Fwarkk, I also wouldn't expect there to be `* 5` when adding the velocity to the position.

Comment: Hmm didn't seem to make any obvious difference ?

Comment: If it doesn't make a difference, the problem lies somewhere else. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you update your player position after creating the bullet, essentially spawning the bullet, then moving your player object left or right.

Make sure you are finished changing player position BEFORE using it to position bullets, camera etc.